# Proof of limits, Spivak

Tags: limits

So when proving that the function $f(x) = \frac 1x$ approaches $\frac 13$ as $x \to 3$ , Spivak does something like:

$$|\frac 1x - \frac 13| < \epsilon$$

he simplifies it to

$$\frac 13 \cdot \frac1{|x|} \cdot |x - 3| $$

so basically he is trying to show that $(x-3)$ is small hence $\epsilon$ is bigger, so $x$ in $x-3$ lies between $2$ and $4$ i.e. $2<x<4 $ and $\frac 1x $ lies between $\frac 14 $ and $\frac 12$ ie. $\frac14 <\frac 1x<\frac 12$

I understand all the way till there however,

he then puts an inequality:

$$\frac 13 \cdot \frac 1{|x|} \cdot |x-3| < \frac 16 |x - 3|$$

I was just wondering if anyone can inform me on where the $\frac 16$ came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're letting $x\to 3$. Since $x$ is close to $3$, we can assume that $|x-3|<1$. Since $||x|-|3||<|x-3|$ we get that $||x|-3|<1$ i.e. $-1<|x|-3<1$. Adding three gives $2<|x|<4$. Inverting gives $$\frac{1}{|x|}<\frac 1 2$$

Comment: that's helpful thanks, but where did he get the 1/6 from?

Comment: @Wangzmk What $2$ times $3$? (Also, you might have mistakenly downvoted instead of upvoting.)

Comment: Oh okay got it. (I didn't down vote, I don't have enough reputation to even up vote.) Thanks